# Pie amChart is not displaying in Chrome

Tags: javascript, svg, amcharts

I'm building a pie graph using amcharts.
The pie is displayed normally in Firfox, meanwhile in Chrome it isn't: 
 [image: this is how the pie is displayed in Firefox:]

[image: And this in Chrome]

html:

```
<div id="performancePieChartDiv" style="width: 295px; height: 83px"></div>
```

js:

```
var performancePieConfig = {
            "type": "pie",
            "angle": 50,
            "depth3D": 15,
            "valueField": "value",
            "titleField": "label",
            "labelsEnabled": false,
            "balloonText" : "[[percents]]%",
            "colors": [
                "#00CC00",
                "#FFAB02",
                "#FF0000"
            ],
            "gradientType": "linear",
            "gradientRatio": [-.4, 0],
            "legend": {
                "position": "right",
                "markerBorderColor": "#000000",
                "markerSize": 8,
                "marginRight" : 0,
                "marginLeft" : 0,
                "verticalGap": 0,
                "valueWidth" : 0,
                "switchable": false
            },
            "outlineAlpha": 1,
            "outlineColor": "#cdcdcd"
        };

    createChart("performancePieChartDiv", performancePieConfig, true, performancePieData, function(retValue) {
    performancePieChart = retValue;
});
```

In the Chrome Console I'm having the error:
**https://localhost/report/amcharts/images/dragIconRoundBigH.svg 404 (Not Found)
https://localhost/report/amcharts/images/dragIconRoundBig.svg 404 (Not Found)**

although this files are located at the needed folder in my local repository.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe change path to relative path first.

Comment: Chrome has a different security model to Firefox. You really should use a web server. Otherwise for Chrome I think you'll need to put all the files in the same directory.